# Bash script to automatically create symlinks to subdirectories in a tree

Tags: bash, whitespace, symlink

Ok, this is my third try posting this, maybe I'm asking the wrong question!!

It's been a few years since I've done any shell programming so I'm a bit rusty...

I'm trying to create a simple shell script that finds all subdirectories under a certain named subdirectory in a tree and creates symbolic links to those directories (sounds more confusing than it is). I'm using cygwin on Windows XP.

This find/grep command finds the directories in the filesystem like I want it to:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep "New Parts"
```

Now for the hard part... I just want to take that list, pipe it into ln and create some symlinks. The list of directories has some whitespace, so I was trying to use xargs to clean things up a bit:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep "New Parts" | xargs -0 ln -s -t /cygdrive/c/Views
```

Unfortunately, ln spits out a long list of all the directories concatenated together (seperated by \n) and spits out a "File name too long" error.

Ideas??

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this all within your find command. OTTOMH:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name "*New Parts*" -exec ln -s -t /cygdrive/c/Views {} \;
```

Hope I remembered that syntax right.

Comment: +1 for the -exec flag. People seem to forget this one a lot. You might want to enclose the {} in quotes though so it handles names with spaces in them ok.

Answer (score 1):

your command

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep "New Parts" | xargs -0 ln -s -t /cygdrive/c/Views
```

have argument "-0" to xargs but you did not tell find to "-print0" (if you did grep could not work in the pipe inbetween). What you want is the following I guess:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep "New Parts" | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 ln -s -t /cygdrive/c/Views
```

The `tr` command will convert newlines to ascii null.

Comment: Use `-name` instead of `grep` as in NWCoder's answer and you can use `-print0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop.

```
for name in $(find $from_dir -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d); do
  ln -s $name $to_dir
done
```

Xargs has issues where the input from the pipe goes at the end of the command.  What you want is multiple commands, not just 1 command.

My experience with doing things within the find command can sometimes be slow, although it does get the job done.

Comment: Your command will fail if one of the directories found contains spaces. You must add quotes, i.e. <<ln -s "$name" $todir>>. That is one of the great benefits of using "xargs -0" that you avoid all such issues.